# C# multi valued combo box value to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void filljobid()
{
    try
    {
        string jobid = "";
        int newjobid, oldjobid;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-CCQ1T25;Initial Catalog=SmartMovers;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(job_id) FROM job", con);

        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            jobid = reader[0].ToString();
        }

        oldjobid = int.Parse(jobid.ToString());
        newjobid = oldjobid + 1;

        jobidtextbox.Text = newjobid.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting");
    }
}

private void fillcustomercombox()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-CCQ1T25;Initial Catalog=SmartMovers;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT customer_id,(first_name + ' ' + last_name + ' - ' + contact) AS CUSTOMERNAME FROM customer", con);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    customeridcombobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    customeridcombobox.DisplayMember = "CUSTOMERNAME";
    customeridcombobox.ValueMember = "customer_id";

    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();

    // CODE FOR DISPLAYING multiple values in another way, but not sure how to retrieve data from this function
    // for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    // {
    //     customeridcombobox.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + " - " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);
    // }
}

private void filldepotcombox()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-CCQ1T25;Initial Catalog=SmartMovers;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT depot_id,(branch_name + ' - ' + region_name + ' - ' + location) AS DEPOTNAME FROM depot", con);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    depotidcombobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    depotidcombobox.DisplayMember = "DEPOTNAME";
    depotidcombobox.ValueMember = "depot_id";

    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
}

private void filljobtypecombox()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-CCQ1T25;Initial Catalog=SmartMovers;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT job_type FROM jobtype", con);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    jobtypecombobox.DisplayMember = "job_type";
    jobtypecombobox.ValueMember = "job_type";
    jobtypecombobox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
}

private void loadingcomboboxesdata_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fillcustomercombox();
    filljobid();
    filldepotcombox();
    filljobtypecombox();
}

private void addnewjobbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-CCQ1T25;Initial Catalog=SmartMoversDB;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into job (start_location, end_location, depot_id, job_type, customer_id,) values ('" + startlocationtxtbox.Text + "','" + endlocationtxtbox.Text + "','" + depotidcombobox.Text + "','" + jobtypecombobox.Text + "','" + customeridcombobox.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Added new job");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is basically take the users selected value which is displayed in the combo box which is valuemember and then insert it into the database. Right now I get the error when I try to insert the data into the database. When I do the combo box with a single value it works fine but it doesn't work when I do it with multiple values.

Comment: What's the error you see getting?

Comment: Which line in the code gives you error?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement - besides being **wide open** to SQL injection - also has a syntax error in it: `insert into job (start_location, end_location, depot_id, job_type, customer_id,)` - remove the last trailing `,` just before the closing parens - it's not needed, it's wrong ....

Comment: You need one set of `values` per selected item for multiple inserts...

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). And your exception handler both eats the real exception information and displays a useless and misleading message. And how many times will you hardcode that connection string in your application?

Answer (score 0):

Could someone close this question. I managed to solve my own question. I dont know if this solution is considered good but here you go.

```
    private void addnewjobbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-CCQ1T25;Initial Catalog=SmartMovers;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            try
            {

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO job(start_location, end_location, depot_id, job_type, customer_id) VALUES ('" + startlocationtxtbox.Text + "','" + endlocationtxtbox.Text + "',@3,@4, @5)"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", startlocationtxtbox.SelectedText);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", endlocationtxtbox.SelectedText);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", depotidcombobox.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", jobtypecombobox.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5",customeridcombobox.SelectedValue);
                    con.Open();
                    if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Record failed");
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE");
            }
        }
    }
```